# I have table as shown below with source,Target and KMS columns and i need out based on KMS columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need the output based on KMS. Table data and expected output:

[image]

1. if KMS is same and source and Target is same(1st and 2nd record are same logically) then consider it as one record
2. If the KMS is same and source and Target is different consider it as different record(consider the last record it has same KMS as 1st record but it different record)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we consider consider each record as a pair and then sort and transpose the source and target accordingly, you should be able to pick out what records go together.

```
with data_from_vijay as(
    select 'Bijapur'    as source, 'Bangalore'  as target, 500 as kms from dual union all
    select 'Bangalore'  as source, 'Bijapur'    as target, 500 as kms from dual union all
    select 'Pune'       as source, 'Bangalore'  as target, 700 as kms from dual union all
    select 'Bangalore'  as source, 'Pune'       as target, 700 as kms from dual union all
    select 'Mangalore'  as source, 'Bangalore'  as target, 400 as kms from dual union all
    select 'Bangalore'  as source, 'Belgaum'    as target, 500 as kms from dual
)
select distinct 
       least(source,    target) as source
      ,greatest(source, target) as target
      ,kms
  from data_from_vijay;
```

The solution does not work for NULLS.

Comment: Thanks Ronnis for quick response, It will work when we know the data.

Comment: But what if we have millions of records in that table

Comment: Then you must size your hardware accordingly :)

Comment: @Vijay, oh... ok :) The first part of my query (WITH data...) is only to show how it works. Obviously it's not part of the solution. You will use only the "SELECT DISTINCT ..." part

Comment: oh...now I got that...:) Thank you so much Ronnis.

Comment: @Vijay, consider accepting the answer if it works for you :)